# Custom Session interfering with acceptance tests

Tags: ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am using `ember-cli-simple-auth` and `ember-cli-simple-auth-devise` in an `ember-cli` project.

I'm also customizing simple-auth's `Session` via an initializer:

```
// app/initializers/custom-session.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';

export default {
  name: 'custom-session',
  before: 'simple-auth',

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    Session.reopen({
      setCurrentUser: function() {
        var id = this.get('user_id'),
            self = this;

        if (!Ember.isEmpty(id)) {
          return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', id)
            .then(function(user) {
              self.set('currentUser', user);
            });
        }
      }.observes('user_id')
    });
  }
};
```

In a simple acceptance test (one that simply calls `ok(1)`), I'm getting the following error

```
Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object  
Source:     
    at Adapter.extend.exception (localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:57907:19)
    at apply (http://localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:21143:27)
    at superWrapper [as exception] (localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:20721:15)
    at RSVP.onerrorDefault (localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:59827:26)
    at Object.__exports__.default.trigger (localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:22673:13)
    at Promise._onerror (localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:23397:16)
    at publishRejection (localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:23804:17)
    at http://localhost:4900/assets/vendor.js:29217:9
```

If I comment out the `self.set('currentUser', user);` line, the error goes away.

What's the appropriate way to handle this? Is there a way to ignore this initializer in tests?

I also get this log message:

> No authorizer factory was configured for Ember Simple Auth - specify one if backend requests need to be authorized.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should update Ember Simple Auth to the latest version 0.6.4 that allows you to specify a custom session class without having to reopen the default Session: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/releases/tag/0.6.4.

Secondly, the warning about the authorizer simply means that requests going to a backend server will not be authorized (e.g. will not have an Authorization header) as no authorizer is defined. That might be ok though depending on your setup.

Regarding the destroyed object problem you could simply check whether the object is destroyed:

```
if (!self.isDestroyed) {
  self.set('currentUser', user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put the custom session class in an ember-cli project?

Comment: I usually create an `app/lib` directory or you could simply define it in the initializer where you configure it.

Comment: Would you then just bypass the ember cli resolver and use a global i.e. name it `App.CustomSession`?

Comment: Nvm, I should just be able to import it in the initializer.